# PHP can't complete MYSQL query in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have a question. This is a simple piece of php that should show the number of rows in a table.

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "1234") or die("Couldn't connect");
mysql_select_db("regulas", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM index", $link) or die("Couldn't finish query");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo $num_rows;

?>
```

However, the page displays:

```
Couldn't connect
```

I'm using a xampp server on my own computer: localhost

What am i doing wrong?

Thx
Jules

Comment: mysql_* functions have been removed from PHP 7, and deprecated in previous versions. It's recommend that you switch to PDO or mysqli. Other than that, check for mysql_errors, that will tell you why.

Comment: What you are doing wrong? Firstly you apparently do not monitor your http servers error log file which is where you can simply _read_ what the issue is instead of having to _guess_.

Comment: As `index` is a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html), it has to be enclosed in backticks to not produce a syntax error in this place.

Comment: I have another script with mysqli but that doesn't work neither

Comment: Il will just check the log files

Comment: It worked, I changed index to siteIndex

Answer (score 1):

You must provide the password in,there is no defauls password in WAMP or XAAXMP try this :

```
    <?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","", "1234") or die("Couldn't   connect");
mysql_select_db("regulas", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM index", $link) or die("Couldn't finish query");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo $num_rows;

?>
```

Read the manual here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: but i have set a password

Answer (score 0):

I changed mysql to mysqli and changed index to siteIndex

```
<?php
```

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "102030!!", "regulas") or die("Couldn't connect");

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM siteIndex") or die("Couldn't finish query");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo $num_rows;

?>